# Simple test case in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I am starting to learn how to use robotframework for testing
I have created following test case to be executed on the local linux host.

```
    *** Settings ***
Library     Process
Suite Teardown  Terminate All Processes     kill=True

*** Test Cases ***
${result} =     Run Process ping 1.1.1.1 -c 1   shell=True  stdout=/home/user/stdout.txt
Log     all output: ${result.stdout}
Should Contain  ${result.stdout}    64 bytes from 1.1.1.1*
```

When i execute this test case I get following out in the terminal:

```
➜  ~ robot firstlinux.robot
==============================================================================
Firstlinux                                                                    
==============================================================================
${result} =                                                           | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Log                                                                   | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'all output: ${result.stdout}' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Should Contain                                                        | FAIL |
No keyword with name '64 bytes from 1.1.1.1*' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Firstlinux                                                            | FAIL |
3 critical tests, 1 passed, 2 failed
3 tests total, 1 passed, 2 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /home/user/output.xml
Log:     /home/user/log.html
Report:  /home/user/report.html
```

How do I get this test to pass, I am checking the stdout and make sure it has the string output from the ping command but looks like robot is not picking this up. I cam see that a stdout.txt file is created which has the results from the stdtout as:

```
➜  ~ ping 1.1.1.1 -c 1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=30.5 ms

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 30.565/30.565/30.565/0.000 ms
```

How do I get the stdout to be displyed in the report that is generated, at the moment I cannot see the output in the report.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that  you haven't properly indented the keywords in your test case. Robot thinks that anything at the left margin is the name of a test case.

You posted this code:

```
*** Test Cases ***
${result} =     Run Process  ping 1.1.1.1 -c 1   shell=True  stdout=/home/user/stdout.txt
Log     all output: ${result.stdout}
Should Contain  ${result.stdout}    64 bytes from 1.1.1.1*
```

In the above, robot thinks that the first test case is named `${result}`. It thinks `Log` is the name of a second test case, and `Should Contain` is the name of a third test case.

The words immediate after those names are assumed to be keywords. That is why it's complaining that `all output: ${result.stdout}`, because that's the first keyword of the "test case" you've named `Log`.

Instead, you need to give your test case a name, and then indent all of those statements. For example, if you want to call this test "Ping test", you would do it like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Ping test
    ${result} =     Run Process ping 1.1.1.1 -c 1   shell=True  stdout=/home/user/stdout.txt
    Log     all output: ${result.stdout}
    Should Contain  ${result.stdout}    64 bytes from 1.1.1.1*
```

Note: you also need two or more spaces after `Run Process`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That solved my problem. When i went through the documentation, i did not pick up the point regarding indentation for test cases.